# Get a list of (local) publications in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication

When in SQL Server Management Studio, there is a "Replication" folder with the list of local publications:

[image: Screen shot]

I am looking for a way to get that list programmatically. Something like a SQL query or a call to a system stored procedure.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think [syspublications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/syspublications-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) has the data you need on a per-database basis. Loop over any database where sys.databases.is_published = 1 and you should find everything you're looking for.

Comment: @BenThul,  Yes, this looks like what I can use.  thank you